# Ubuntu font causes strange select borders in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, drop-down-menu

I am using the Ubuntu font from Google fonts in my project. Unfortunately when using the fonts, Firefox does not show the right border of selects/dropdowns.

I have created a fiddle, [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/bvencel/WX2xT/5/) with Firefox.

[image: Border disappearing in Firefox]

Relevant code

```
<link 
    href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
    input, textarea, select, span
    {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu' , sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 13px;
    }​
</style>

<span>Some text to show that the font is indeed in use</span>
<br />
<select name="testSelect" id="testSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>​
```

Comment: I can see proper border in my Firefox.

Comment: Apparently in some FF browser it renders correctly, in some it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Please set **width** selects/dropdowns.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set an exact width, but I will try min-width

Comment: Nor width, nor min-width helped. Some selects are still missing their right border.

Answer (score 0):

As much as this might not be the answer you're looking for, *in general*, I try to avoid styling `<select>` elements directly. What properties 'take' in one browser versus another seems to vary widely, so it never seems to work correctly. For instance, I checked your jsFiddle out in Chrome, and the drop down ignored your Ubuntu font declaration altogether. That's just how Chrome rolls.

So, my suggestion would be to remove the styling for `select` in your stylesheet and just let the browsers do their thing. The upshot of this approach is that a user will get a drop down that they are familiar with *in their browser*.

All that said, if you REALLY need to style a drop down, there are methods out there for basically hijacking a `<select>` element with javascript, and replacing it with a bunch of divs. I like the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) library for this sort of thing. As it renders `<div>`'s on the page, you can style those to your heart's content.

Comment: Besides the font I am not styling the SELECT at all. Unfortunately I am in this situation because I had to set the font. Thank you for the Chosen library idea!